# android - picasso load image by url in listview doesn't work

Tags: java, android, image, url, picasso

I'm trying to add simple image by url using picasso and it doesn't work in my project.

- I downloaded the .jar file from the picasso website and moved it into the app->libs folder.
- I even added the compile sentence - `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` to dependencies and synced my project.

Can anyone know what's the problem?

The code in the mainActivity.java:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagetry);
        Picasso.with(this).load("https://i.pinimg.com/564x/58/01/02/5801020fea36221ffba33633f99a7d81--small-heart-tattoos-heart-tattoo-designs.jpg").into(img);
```

The code in activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetry"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**thanks!**

Comment: Which error do you get? What foes wrong?

Comment: Two Things:
1. Above image Url is not showing image in browser itself.
2. Possibility of your image url is private, need to make it public.

Comment: Thanks everyone! i searched in another question and discovered that the problem was to add the internet permission in the AndroidManifet.xml.